# Laravel 'sail mysql' command connects without any creditials

Tags: laravel, database

friends.
Since I am new to Laravel sail and docker in general, I can't realy understand, is it a bug or a feature:
When trying this command: "$ ./vendor/bin/sail mysql", I'm automaticly get in MySQL cli whithout asking any creditials.
I supose that's not quite secure behavior.
I'd tried to set MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD paran to '0' in my docker-compose, but that brang no any visible effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a convenience feature.

[Sail automatically uses the password defined in the `.env` file](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/bin/sail#L389) (as well as user and database) to connect to MySQL. Since Sail is only intended for local development and the password is already saved in `.env` there shouldn't be any additional security concerns.